# Code to for AutoMapper complex mapping

Tags: vb.net, automapper

**AutoMapper with VB.NET**

I have the following classes below. OrderA With List (Of OrderALineItem) and OrderBList With List (Of OrderB). I want to copy data from OrderA to OrderBList. Which copies ItemName, ItemQty, Price from List (Of OrderALineItem) to List (Of OrderB) and OrderID, CustomerName from OrderA itself. I have found almost all codes in C# and am not able to convert it to vb.net code.

```
Public Class OrderA
    Public Property OrderID As String
    Public Property CustomerName As String
    Public Property OrderLineItem As List(Of OrderALineItem)
End Class
Public Class OrderALineItem
    Public Property ItemName As String
    Public Property ItemQty As Integer
    Public Property Price As Decimal
End Class

Public Class OrderBList
    Public Property OrderBLineItem As List(Of OrderB)
End Class

Public Class OrderB

    Public Property OrderID As String
    Public Property CustomerName As String
    Public Property ItemName As String
    Public Property ItemQty As Integer
    Public Property Price As Decimal

End Class
```

My VB.NET code until now is:

```
Dim mapperConfiguration = New MapperConfiguration(Sub(config)
                                                    config.CreateMap(Of OrderALineItem, OrderBList)()
                                                End Sub)
Dim mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper()
Dim objOrderB = mapper.Map(Of OrderBList)(objOrder.OrderLineItem)
```

The above code creates and object from copies the data from objOrder.OrderLineItem to OrderBList. That's it.
Can anybody help me out on this in **VB.NET**.

***Note:*** *Am totally new in AutoMapper*

Version: **AutoMapper 6.2.2.0**

Answer (score 2):

**Done myself, I hope the code below will be helpful to somebody.**

```html
Dim mapperConfiguration = New MapperConfiguration(Sub(config)
                                                      config.AddProfile(New CustomProfile_1)
                                                  End Sub)

Dim objMapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper()

Dim objOrderB As List(Of Dest_OrderB) = objMapper.Map(Of Src_OrderA, List(Of Dest_OrderB))(objOrderA)

Public Class CustomProfile_1
    Inherits Profile
    Sub New()

        CreateMap(Of Src_OrderALineItem, Dest_OrderB)()

        CreateMap(Of Src_OrderA, List(Of Dest_OrderB))() _
            .ConstructProjectionUsing(
                Function(Src1) Src1.List_Src_OrderALineItem.Select(Function(Src2) New Dest_OrderB _
                    With {.CustomerName = Src1.CustomerName,
                            .OrderID = Src1.OrderID,
                            .ItemName = Src2.ItemName,
                            .ItemQty = Src2.ItemQty,
                            .Price = Src2.Price}
                            ).ToList())


    End Sub
End Class
```